# Creating PDF with Nodejs send this to Client with AJAX response

Tags: node.js, ajax, pdfkit

Im setting a portal that create PDF with some data, the code is working saving the pdf file in the server but I need to send this to the client with ajax response.

Im using NodeJs in the server side with the PDFkit Library.

NodePdfserverside.js

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
var fs = require('fs');
var doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.fontSize(15).text("Fecha:", 160, 40);
doc.pipe(res);
doc.end();
```

JavaScriptFile.js

```
 $('#generatepdf').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
    url: '/ITgenearpdf',
        type: 'GET',
    dataType: "application/pdf",
        data: {<data send to server side>},
    timeout: 5000,
    responseType: 'blob',
        success: function(data) {
        var blob=new Blob([data]);
            var link=document.createElement('a');
            link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download="out.pdf";
        link.click();
        $.getScript('/js/Alert.js', function() { 
        var elem = {text: 'Created', bgColor: '#BC7102'};
                    makeAlert(elem); });
        $('#loader').addClass('hide-loader');
        },
    error: function() { 
        $.getScript('/js/Alert.js', function() { 
        var elem = {text: 'error', bgColor: '#AB0202'};
            makeAlert(elem); });
        $('#loader').addClass('hide-loader');
         },
  });
```